# Error in sections with documentclass amsart

Tags: chapters, article, amsart, section-titles

I'm trying to submit a paper to a journal, and they ask to do the article in class `\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}`. First I made the text with the command `\documentclass[10pt]{article}`. I changed the commands, but it started to give errors in the sections, that is, in the command `\section`. This happened throughout the text.If you remove this command, the compilation takes place without errors. Below I'm writing the commands I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ch}{char}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}\linenumbers


\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Let $A$ be an associative algebra over a field $K$ ...
\end{document}
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me with this error.

Thank you.

Comment: before the error you get a warning that tocloft is incompatible. removing that package makes the error go.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle. It worked!

Comment: don't ignore warnings:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the error you get a warning that `tocloft` is incompatible. Removing that package makes the error go.

```
Package tocloft Warning: \@starttoc has already been redefined; tocloft bailing                                                                                          
 out. on input line 1156.
```